# Premature end of script headers wsgi with flask on xampp

Tags: apache, xampp, flask, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I am trying to run a flask app with mod_wsgi on an apache server running through xampp.
I have tried reading all the questions already asked and gone through the wiki for wsgi but i still cant seem to find why im getting this error.
I am on a debian 6 with python 2.6.6
My httpd.conf :

```
WSGIDaemonProcess debug_tool user=spyglass group=root threads=5
WSGIScriptAlias /debug_tool /opt/lampp/htdocs/spyglass_v2/debug_tool/debug_tool.wsgi
<Directory /opt/lampp/htdocs/spyglass_v2/debug_tool>
  WSGIProcessGroup debug_tool
  WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

my debug_tool.wsgi:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"/opt/lampp/htdocs/spyglass_v2/debug_tool/")
from debug_tool import app as application
```

My debug_tool folder looks like this:

```
ls -rtl
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root 4096 Dec 18 19:36 uploads
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root 4096 Dec 18 19:36 Testing_Paramerters
drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root 4096 Dec 18 19:36 templates
-rw-r--r-- 1 root     root 4688 Dec 19 14:42 debug_tool.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 spyglass root 3859 Dec 19 14:43 debug_tool.pyc
-rw-r--r-- 1 spyglass root  118 Dec 19 15:17 debug_tool.wsgi
```

my deubg_tool.py looks like this:

```
import os
import re
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

@app.route('/',methods=['GET'])
def hello_world():

return 'hello world'
```

Do you know what could be wrong?

**Update:**

I get it when i try to import flask. What could this mean?

Error log:

[Thu Dec 20 12:09:49 2012] [error] [client 172.20.31.135] Premature end of script headers: debug_tool.wsgi
[Thu Dec 20 12:09:49 2012] [notice] child pid 20206 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)

And the python script is indented properly in the actual file. It can import re and os fine but as soon as i try to import flask i get that error

I looked at my httpd.conf file and i am loading mod_php5.
Is it possible to run both? I went to 
http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#The_Apache_Alias_Directive
But could not figure out how to run both modules.

My overall goal is to just add this tool using mod_wsgi to a preexisting server running the mod_php5. Thanks

Comment: Can  you post the relevant parts of HTTPd's error.log?

Comment: Just to be sure, have you forgotten to format indentation in python code above here or this is how your code looks?

Comment: Try going through things listed in the mod_wsgi FAQ and documentation. http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Apache_Process_Crashes For a start, are you loading mod_php or mod_python into same Apache.

Comment: I looked at the http.conf file and its loading php4_module and php5_module.

Comment: I am trying to just add my tool on top of the original server that is using php5_module so is it possible to load mod_wsgi when someone access the tool and otherwise uses the mod_php5 or something along those lines?

Comment: I went here http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationGuidelines#The_Apache_Alias_Directive
And tried looking how to do such a thing and i think its:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /site.wsgi/$1 [QSA,PT,L]
But im not too sure about what i have to change for it to fit my configurations

Answer (score 0):

Premature end of script headers is almost always a stack trace due to an Exception, in my experience.

Since you do not yet have a large enough project to have logging going yet, I would suggest simply wrapping everything in a try-except that prints to stderr

```
try:
  YOUR SCRIPT CONTENTS HERE
except Exception, ex:        
  import sys

  from traceback import format_list, extract_tb

  (extype, value, trace) = sys.exc_info()

  print >> sys.stderr, "%s:%s\n%s" % (extype, value, ''.join(format_list(extract_tb(trace))))
```

then check for the output in apache's logs which are probably at

`/var/log/httpd/error_log`